# H2O ML Python cheatsheet OR Comparison between H2O's Python API and scikit-learn

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, h2o

I wanted to ask if anyone has come across a h2o machine learning python cheatsheet or comparison between h2o using python and scikit-learn

Would be very helpful since I am a scikit-learn guy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- There is a H2OFrame / Pandas DataFrame munging cheatsheet
  [here](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-docs/src/cheatsheets/Python_H2OFrame_PandasDataFrame_Parity.md).
- The "EEG Eyestate" demo was written for both [H2O](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-py/demos/H2O_tutorial_eeg_eyestate.ipynb) and [Scikit-learn](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-py/demos/EEG_eyestate_sklearn_NOPASS.ipynb), so that's the closest thing to a side-to-side comparison that I can point you to.
- There are some Python tutorials
  [here](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-tutorials#python-tutorials), which demonstrate basic usage of the supervised H2O algos (and grid search) in Python.
- Taylor Smith created the [skutil](https://github.com/tgsmith61591/skutil) module which allows you to use H2O models more easily with sklearn pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

For algorithms and examples in Python for how to use each parameter, go here (the main H2O user documentation) and look at the Algorithms section:

- http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/index.html

For Python specific stuff, go to the docs website and search for 'Python' on the page.  There's a box specifically with Python stuff:

- http://docs.h2o.ai

You can use H2O models as elements of an sklearn pipeline.

Comment: Thanks Tom.Yes, I have been through these docs. And saw that there is so much similarity between h2o's python APIs and scikit learn. Also there is similarity between h2o data munging and pandas data wrangling. So I was looking for a side-by-side comparison of syntax, or a h2o data munging and ML cheatsheet.